# Finding the one-dimensional wave equation the vibrating string

Tags: vibrations, string

It's a relatively simple problem and I've been able to solve it in a different way before, but the current book I'm learning from left me with some questions:

After a few idealizations we get the following:

$F_u = \tau (\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x+\Delta x)-\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x))$

Where $F_u$ is the force in the vertical direction, $\tau$ is the tension of the string, $u$ is the displacement in the vertical direction and $x$ is the horizontal position.

Apparently, this equation should lead to:

$F_u = \tau (\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}\Delta x+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2))$

Now, I have no idea how to get to this and I don't have any idea what the $\mathcal{O}$ signifies (I found the Latex code thanks to detexify).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F_u=\tau\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\Delta x+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)\right)$ is a [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $F_u$  around $x$. The $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ means that there are further terms, which all include a factor of $\Delta x^n$ for $n>1$, i.e. for $\Delta x \ll 1$ these terms are negligable.

Generally, for a function $f(y)$ the Taylor expansion around $y_0$ is
$$
f(y)\approx f(y_0)+f'(y_0)\cdot (y-y_0)+\mathcal{O}\left((y-y_0)^2\right).
$$
To get to the result above we just use $f\rightarrow\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $y_0\rightarrow x$ and $y-y_0\rightarrow\Delta x$. This will give you
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x+\Delta x)\approx\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x)+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x)\cdot\Delta x+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2).$$
Just plug this in your expression to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the definition of the (forward) derivative, it's probably only notation that is holding you back here. It might be more clear if you consider:

$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2} = \lim_{\Delta x->0} \frac{(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x+\Delta x)-\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x))}{\Delta x}$

Just think of $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x)$ as a function.

Since you are not taking the limit you introduce an error which is of the order of $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x)$, so you get.

$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2} = \frac{(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x+\Delta x)-\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x))}{\Delta x} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x)$

multiplying by $\Delta x$ yields

$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x+\Delta x)-\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x)=\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}\Delta x+\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$

Minus signs can be absorbed in the $\mathcal{O}$